# Creating field value "unique" throughout the collection in Django MongoDB models?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am having hard time to understand how to make field value unique while using [Django MongoDB](http://django-mongodb.org).my models.py has a model:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projectName =models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True)
    projectManager = EmbeddedModelField('Users')
```

Here i want whenever a new project instance is added it should have unique projectName.But this code is not working out as it allows adding same value for projectName and doesn't give me error.I read its possible to make field value Unique by using indexes in pymongo but how do I do it in [Django MongoDB](http://django-mongodb.org).

Comment: What DB do you use? Have you added the `unique` parameter after running `syncdb`?

Comment: I am using MongoDB with Django MongoDB wrapper and yes i added the unique parameter before running syncdb

Comment: Probably django does not reproduce the fields correctly. Can you extract the list of indices? mongo shell -> use <your db> -> db.<your collection>.getIndices()

Comment: [
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "API.Users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        }
]

Comment: So, it didn't create a unique index. Well, I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Answer to my own question is I had to add `unique=True` for model field before doing syncdb.Thanks to culebron.Its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question is I had to add unique=True for model field before doing syncdb.Thanks to culebron.Its working now